Rational distance problem - Straight line version
I am looking for the following set of rational coordinate points on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Set of point $P$ which has rational distances from points $(-3,0),(-1,0),(1,0),(3,0)$.

I know the problem is unsolved if four points are vertices of the unit square. (ref: Rational_distance_problem_square_version) However, I cannot find references of other configurations of four points (including straight line position).
Current progress

Coordinate based approach. Let $P=(d, h)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$. Followings should be all rational square. $(d-1)^2+h^2, (d+1)^2+h^2, (d-3)^2+h^2, (d+3)^2+h^2$. To make $(d-1)^2+h^2$ rational square, parametrize $h=\frac{d-1}{2}(r-\frac{1}{r})$ for $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. Substituting this into other three gives messy equations. I think this approach might be related to elliptic curves.

Distance based approach. Denote $D_{-3},D_{-1},D_1,D_3$ be distances between $P$ and $(-3,0),(-1,0),(1,0),(3,0)$ respectively. Then $d=\frac{(D_{-1}^2-D_1^2)}{4}=\frac{(D_{-3}^2-D_3^2)}{12}$. Using Heron's triangle area formula, $h=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{((D_1+D_{-1})^2-4)(4-(D_1-D_{-1})^2)}=\frac{1}{12}\sqrt{((D_3+D_{-3})^2-36)(36-(D_3-D_{-3})^2)}$. I think this approach might be related to Diophantine equations.


Can anyone give ideas or references? Thank you.

Edit, Further progress on 2
Letting $A_1=D_1+D_{-1}$, $A_2=D_1-D_{-1}$, $B_1=D_3+D_{-3}$, $B_2=D_3-D_{-3}$ changes the first and second equations into

$3A_1A_2=B_1B_2$
$B_1^2+B_2^2=A_1^2+A_2^2+32$

Can anyone parametrize them?

I believe $(0,0)$ is the only integer point that works along the line $x=0$.
